# No suitable HttpMessageConverter for Response

Tags: android, spring, resttemplate

I am a beginner in android.I need to call a spring web service in my android project which returns a class object as response. Below is the code used to call the web service.

```
int nID=4;
RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
CoaAccountList accList=restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/SpringProject/getCoaList/{parentId}", CoaAccountList.class, nID);
```

Below is the controller code where the web-service will comes to hit.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getCoaList/{parentId}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody CoaAccountList getCoaList(@PathVariable(value ="parentId") Integer parentId) {
    try{
        System.out.println("coaacclist ");
        CoaAccountList coaAccList=new CoaAccountList();
        List<COAAccount> accountList= saveitDao.getAccounts(parentId);
        coaAccList.setCoaList(accountList);
        return coaAccList;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exc on list "+e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm getting:

```
 org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type[com.example.myandroidproject.CoaAccountList] and content type [application/json].
```

I don't know how to convert this response to CoaAccountList object in Android. How to do that? I also have another web-service which returns a jsonstring, which is working perfectly.

```
String accList=restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/SpringProject/getAllAccounts/{parentId}", String.class, nID);
```

Below is the spring configuration file.

servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.save" />

<!-- <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean> -->

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver"/>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/views.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SpringProject"/>
<property name="username" value="root"/>
<property name="password" value="password"/>
<property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
</bean>

 <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
<property name="packagesToScan">
  <array>
    <value>com.example.save</value>
  </array>
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
  <value>
    hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
  </value>
</property>
</bean>
<!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
<!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: may you post also the spring configuration? Which kind of spring viewresolver are you using?

Comment: I think the problem is on converting the response to CoaAccountList

Answer (score 1):

As I cans ee you are using a TilesViewResolver; this viewResolver tries to respond in HTML; I suggest to you to use a org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver (an article is available here [Spring ContentNegotingViewResolver](https://spring.io/blog/2013/06/03/content-negotiation-using-views)

Basically the point is that spring tries to respond in HTML since you are using the TilesViewResolver; you need, instead, a JSON response
In this "mix" kind of response, the  ContentNegotiatingViewResolver can help you

Comment: So i need to add ContentNegotiatingViewResolver in my spring config file.right?Then does i need to add any converters in android side where the webservice is called

Comment: How to configure this Spring ContentNegotingViewResolver for my case.Can you explain it